# asp.net core 2 - Custom model binding for specific field

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a model:

```
public class ChartFilter
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tiene que especificar una fecha")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "La fecha es invalido")]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha desde")]
    public DateTime dateFrom { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tiene que especificar una fecha")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "La fecha es invalido")]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha hasta")]
    public DateTime dateTo { get; set; }
}
```

My handler/action:

```
 public void OnGetFilter([FromQuery(Name = "ChartFilterForForm")]ChartFilter chartFilter) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            initComprobantes(chartFilter);
        }
        else {
            initComprobantes();
        }
    }
```

My form:

```
<form name="filter" class="form-horizontal">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-1" asp-for="ChartFilterForForm.dateFrom"></label>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" asp-format="{0:d \de MMMM \de yyyy}" asp-for="ChartFilterForForm.dateFrom" />
            </div>

            <label class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-1" asp-for="ChartFilterForForm.dateTo"></label>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="datetime" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:d \de MMMM \de yyyy}" asp-for="ChartFilterForForm.dateTo" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px">
            <input asp-page-handler="Filter" class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" value="Filtrar" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

The problem is, asp cannot validate the model automatically with the date I sent. It gave me the error `The value '4 de eneror de 2017' is not valid for Fecha desde.`.

I tried the custom binding. But to use the custom binding I will have to set the field values manually like from there [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding). But I just want to set only the dates value.

I see a lot of articles and posts on the web that people talking about setting the locale. But my problem is not the local. Because I am using my own date format like: 1 January of 2017 or monday 1 januaryof 2017. For example: I use Symfony and in Symfony I can change the form value in my controller before the framework validate the form. That's what I am trying to do with asp.net core.

How can I just do that for only the DateTime fields?

Comment: the link is returning a  404.

Comment: I set the link to the local en-en instead of en-us. It's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think c# `DateTime` can parse your format automatically, due to the different language format. If the browser language settings are correct, the input form should automatically convert the format. However, in your example, there is no `type` on the first date input, which might be why it's not even trying to parse.

There is a new `date` input type, which removes the time element. If you use this, your users will get a date picker, rather than entering a string.

Comment: The `date` input type does not work on Firefox. I use jQuery UI for a date picker. But this is not the problem. I see a lot of articles and posts on the web that people talking about setting the locale. But my problem is not the local. Because I am using my own date format like: 1 January of 2017 or monday 1 januaryof 2017. For example: I use Symfony and in Symfony I can change the form value in my controller before the framework validate the form. That's what I am trying to do with asp.net core.

Comment: It's not about the HTML date input type because I get the error for both date input. And using that format: `2017/1/25` work

Comment: Like I said, I just don't want to do the things manually because my form will be huge. I prefer asp.net to do it for me. But if I was doing it manually, that code would do the trick: `dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("wednesday 25 january of 2017", "dddd d MMMM \\o\\f yyyy", null);` I just want to be able to do that for only on my DateTime fields.